# the assertionerror when run py-faster-rcnn

Tags: python, github

When I tried to run the py-faster-rcnn followed the README.md in Github：
./experiments/scripts/faster_rcnn_alt_opt.sh 0 VGG_CNN_M_1024 pascal_voc

And it stuck in stage like this:
AssertionError: Path does not exist: /home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/data/VOCdevkit2007/VOC2007/ImageSets/Main/trainval.txt

```
+ set -e
+ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ GPU_ID=0
+ NET=VGG_CNN_M_1024
+ NET_lc=vgg_cnn_m_1024
+ DATASET=pascal_voc
+ array=($@)
+ len=3
+ EXTRA_ARGS=
+ EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG=
+ case $DATASET in
+ TRAIN_IMDB=voc_2007_trainval
+ TEST_IMDB=voc_2007_test
+ PT_DIR=pascal_voc
+ ITERS=40000
++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
+ LOG=experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_.txt.2016-07-30_19-36-05
+ exec
++ tee -a experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_.txt.2016-07-30_19-36-05
+ echo Logging output to experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_.txt.2016-07-30_19-36-05
Logging output to experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_.txt.2016-07-30_19-36-05
+ ./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py --gpu 0 --net_name VGG_CNN_M_1024 --weights data/imagenet_models/VGG_CNN_M_1024.v2.caffemodel --imdb voc_2007_trainval --cfg experiments/cfgs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt.yml
Called with args:
Namespace(cfg_file='experiments/cfgs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt.yml', gpu_id=0, imdb_name='voc_2007_trainval', net_name='VGG_CNN_M_1024', pretrained_model='data/imagenet_models/VGG_CNN_M_1024.v2.caffemodel', set_cfgs=None)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Stage 1 RPN, init from ImageNet model
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Init model: data/imagenet_models/VGG_CNN_M_1024.v2.caffemodel
Using config:
{'DATA_DIR': '/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/data',
 'DEDUP_BOXES': 0.0625,
 'EPS': 1e-14,
 'EXP_DIR': 'faster_rcnn_alt_opt',
 'GPU_ID': 0,
 'MATLAB': 'matlab',
 'MODELS_DIR': '/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/models/pascal_voc',
 'PIXEL_MEANS': array([[[ 102.9801,  115.9465,  122.7717]]]),
 'RNG_SEED': 3,
 'ROOT_DIR': '/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn',
 'TEST': {'BBOX_REG': True,
          'HAS_RPN': True,
          'MAX_SIZE': 1000,
          'NMS': 0.3,
          'PROPOSAL_METHOD': 'selective_search',
          'RPN_MIN_SIZE': 16,
          'RPN_NMS_THRESH': 0.7,
          'RPN_POST_NMS_TOP_N': 300,
          'RPN_PRE_NMS_TOP_N': 6000,
          'SCALES': [600],
          'SVM': False},
 'TRAIN': {'ASPECT_GROUPING': True,
           'BATCH_SIZE': 128,
           'BBOX_INSIDE_WEIGHTS': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
           'BBOX_NORMALIZE_MEANS': [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
           'BBOX_NORMALIZE_STDS': [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2],
           'BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS': True,
           'BBOX_NORMALIZE_TARGETS_PRECOMPUTED': False,
           'BBOX_REG': False,
           'BBOX_THRESH': 0.5,
           'BG_THRESH_HI': 0.5,
           'BG_THRESH_LO': 0.0,
           'FG_FRACTION': 0.25,
           'FG_THRESH': 0.5,
           'HAS_RPN': True,
           'IMS_PER_BATCH': 1,
           'MAX_SIZE': 1000,
           'PROPOSAL_METHOD': 'gt',
           'RPN_BATCHSIZE': 256,
           'RPN_BBOX_INSIDE_WEIGHTS': [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],
           'RPN_CLOBBER_POSITIVES': False,
           'RPN_FG_FRACTION': 0.5,
           'RPN_MIN_SIZE': 16,
           'RPN_NEGATIVE_OVERLAP': 0.3,
           'RPN_NMS_THRESH': 0.7,
           'RPN_POSITIVE_OVERLAP': 0.7,
           'RPN_POSITIVE_WEIGHT': -1.0,
           'RPN_POST_NMS_TOP_N': 2000,
           'RPN_PRE_NMS_TOP_N': 12000,
           'SCALES': [600],
           'SNAPSHOT_INFIX': 'stage1',
           'SNAPSHOT_ITERS': 10000,
           'USE_FLIPPED': True,
           'USE_PREFETCH': False},
 'USE_GPU_NMS': True}
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 114, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py", line 122, in train_rpn
    roidb, imdb = get_roidb(imdb_name)
  File "./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py", line 61, in get_roidb
    imdb = get_imdb(imdb_name)
  File "/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/datasets/factory.py", line 38, in get_imdb
    return __sets[name]()
  File "/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/datasets/factory.py", line 20, in <lambda>
    __sets[name] = (lambda split=split, year=year: pascal_voc(split, year))
  File "/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/datasets/pascal_voc.py", line 38, in __init__
    self._image_index = self._load_image_set_index()
  File "/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/datasets/pascal_voc.py", line 82, in _load_image_set_index
    'Path does not exist: {}'.format(image_set_file)
AssertionError: Path does not exist: /home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/data/VOCdevkit2007/VOC2007/ImageSets/Main/trainval.txt
```

What should I do? I checked the trainval.txt file before I built the symbolic link, it existed. I don't know what happened after I built the symbolic link, I cannot open this file any more.

And I changed my command like this:
./experiments/scripts/faster_rcnn_alt_opt.sh 0 VGG_CNN_M_1024 pascal_voc   --set EXP_DIR foobar RNG_SEED 42 TRAIN.SCALES "[400, 500, 600, 700]"

It stuck with another AssertionError again:

- set -e
- export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
- PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
- GPU_ID=0
- NET=VGG_CNN_M_1024
- NET_lc=vgg_cnn_m_1024
- DATASET=pascal_voc
- array=($@)
- len=13
- EXTRA_ARGS='--set EXP_DIR foobar RNG_SEED 42 TRAIN.SCALES [400, 500, 600, 700]'
- EXTRA_ARGS_SLUG='--set_EXP_DIR_foobar_RNG_SEED_42_TRAIN.SCALES_[400,_500,_600,_700]'
- case $DATASET in
- TRAIN_IMDB=voc_2007_trainval
- TEST_IMDB=voc_2007_test
- PT_DIR=pascal_voc
- ITERS=40000
  ++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
- LOG='experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_--set_EXP_DIR_foobar_RNG_SEED_42_TRAIN.SCALES_[400,_500,_600,_700].txt.2016-07-30_19-41-43'
- exec
  ++ tee -a 'experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_--set_EXP_DIR_foobar_RNG_SEED_42_TRAIN.SCALES_[400,_500,_600,_700].txt.2016-07-30_19-41-43'
- echo Logging output to 'experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_--set_EXP_DIR_foobar_RNG_SEED_42_TRAIN.SCALES_[400,_500,_600,_700].txt.2016-07-30_19-41-43'
  Logging output to experiments/logs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt_VGG_CNN_M_1024_--set_EXP_DIR_foobar_RNG_SEED_42_TRAIN.SCALES_[400,_500,_600,_700].txt.2016-07-30_19-41-43
- ./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py --gpu 0 --net_name VGG_CNN_M_1024 --weights data/imagenet_models/VGG_CNN_M_1024.v2.caffemodel --imdb voc_2007_trainval --cfg experiments/cfgs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt.yml --set EXP_DIR foobar RNG_SEED 42 TRAIN.SCALES '[400,' 500, 600, '700]'
  Called with args:
  Namespace(cfg_file='experiments/cfgs/faster_rcnn_alt_opt.yml', gpu_id=0, imdb_name='voc_2007_trainval', net_name='VGG_CNN_M_1024', pretrained_model='data/imagenet_models/VGG_CNN_M_1024.v2.caffemodel', set_cfgs=['EXP_DIR', 'foobar', 'RNG_SEED', '42', 'TRAIN.SCALES', '[400,', '500,', '600,', '700]'])
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/train_faster_rcnn_alt_opt.py", line 212, in 
  cfg_from_list(args.set_cfgs)
  File "/home/jiaxin/py-faster-rcnn/tools/../lib/fast_rcnn/config.py", line 268, in cfg_from_list
  assert len(cfg_list) % 2 == 0
  AssertionError

What should I do? Please help me!

Comment: Please add the error as text instead of image.

Comment: Yes, I modified it. Please help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I just googled the solution for the second error. The credit comes from @faschinj https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn/issues/132.

Make sure there are no spaces after the commas otherwise they are parsed as separate arguments like so TRAIN.SCALES "[400,500,600,700]"

Answer (score 0):

I think it’s the error of symlink. My solution is that firstly delete the symlink ’VOCdevkit2007’ in folder ‘data’. And then copy the folder ‘VOCdevkit’ into folder ‘data’, and rename it as ‘VOCdevkit2007’.

Comment: Please check [how to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Add more details to justify your answer.

Answer (score 0):

when creating a symlinks, using

```
ln -s ./VOCdevkit ./VOCdevkit2007
```

instead of

```
ln -s $VOCdevkit VOCdevkit2007
```

Because the author maybe has created the variable `$VOCdevkit` while we didn't. Then the `ln` command will link `VOCdevkit2007` to itself:

```
'./VOCdevkit2007' -> 'VOCdevkit2007'
```